# Understanding Fetch() Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I am going through a javascript tutorial, and I need some help in understanding the pattern in the following function:

```
get:  function(url) {
         return fetch(rootUrl + url, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + apiKey
            }
        } )
        .then(
            function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        );
    }
```

What I am confused about is, what is the point of returning fetch() if we only actually care about response.json()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` `fetch` for ability to chain `.then()`, `.catch()` to `.get()` call, e.g.,

```
obj.get(url).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

without `return` statement `obj.get(url).then(handler)` could log error if  object does not have property named `then` where value is a function which handles `Promise` returned from `fetch`, where no value is returned from `get` function

```js
var objWithReturn = {
  get: function(url) {
    return Promise.resolve(url)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          return JSON.parse(response);
        }
      );
  }
}

objWithReturn.get('{"a":1}')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

```js
var objWithoutReturn = {
  get: function(url) {
    Promise.resolve(url)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          return JSON.parse(response);
        }
      );
  }
}

objWithoutReturn.get('{"a":1}')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Comment: There's a typo in second example. should be: `objWithoutReturn`

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning `fetch()`. When you write chained function calls like:

```
return f1(args).f2(otherargs);
```

it's equivalent to:

```
var temp1 = f1(args);
var temp2 = temp1.f2(otherargs);
return temp2;
```

So your function could be written as:

```
get: function(url) {
    var promise1 = fetch(rootUrl + url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + apiKey
        }
    });
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
    return promise2;
}
```

Now you can see that it returns the promise that, when it's fullfilled, returns the JSON from the response.